# GUI Window Switching without a DE

Tags: command-line, gui

I usually run Ubuntu in a chroot on a ChromeBook, within a [xiwi](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/wiki/crouton-in-a-Chromium-OS-window-(xiwi)) window. I didn't install a DE, so when I start it up, I just open an LXTerminal to start stuff from there. I really like CLI, and not having a DM or DE taking up overhead. With xiwi, I can easily click between windows with little tabs at the top.

I'd like to run my full Ubuntu install machine like this. CLI most of the time, opening GUI applications only as needed. How can I switch between multiple GUI windows when I don't have a DM/DE installed?

Comment: Install the wm of your choice openbox, fluxbox, see https://www.slant.co/topics/390/~best-window-managers-for-linux for additional options